# Preventing double click of button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent

I have a link which acts as a button. And the code for it is as follows in the code-

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Name="BreadcrumbButton"
                                Margin="2,2,2,2"       

                                Content="{Binding Label}"
                                Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource SelectableBreadcrumbStyle}"
                                Cursor="Hand" >


                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Text=" > "
                                   Style="{StaticResource BaseLinkTextStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

I want it to call the SelectCommand only on single click and not  on double click. For the same, I tried adding the MouseDoubleClick and redirected it to BreadCrumbButton_OnMouse function where I have set e.Handled as true. This did not prevent it from calling SelectCommand. So I tried the following too -

```
<Button.InputBindings>
         <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" />
</Button.InputBindings>
```

But still control moves to SelectCommand on double click. 
Is there some thing else I should try?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you use the events instead of command?

Comment: In general, double-click should always be an extension of single-click. I.e. the single-click always happens, and double-click adds to it. It's fine for single-click to do _nothing_. But to require single-click to do something completely different from double-click is contrary to usual UI guidelines for good code. That said, if you insist, you can always have in your single-click handler a delay, to wait to see if a double-click is also generated. Then suppress the single-click behavior if a double-click appears within the allotted time (i.e. the double-click time).